# Entity Framework 6 with MYSQL (Visual Studio Development > Visual Studio Integrate)

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, entity-framework-6

I am new to Dot Net Technology. I having issue to generate edmx model from the MYSQL database using the ADO.Net Entity Data Model. Everything run well on the wizard, however the usual screen for selection of tables, views etc do not display and the wizard close after create the connection without error. It worked previously when I run on Entity Framework 5 and I am able to select the tables for edmx generation after create the connection.

I am running on

Visual Studio 2013

Entity Framework 6.1.3

MySQL.Data 6.9.7

MySQL.Data.Entity 6.9.7

Hope anyone familiar can help me. Thanks in advance.

TH

Comment: Do u have found any solutions? I gget the same error

Answer (score 1):

Do you have MySQL's Connector/NET installed on your computer? If so it's probably because 6.9.7 isn't "released" yet and you have 6.9.6 installed on the PC, which is causing something to crap out. Try reverting the packages to 6.9.6 and see if it works, I know it did for me.